# TinyMCE: register custom editor mode

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-6

As we know TinyMCE has two built-in editor modes: designer and readonly.
The problem is that in readonly mode not only the content is non editable but also the toolbars are disabled, so for example search plugin does not work.

I'm trying to register my own custom mode that would allow me to mix two modes blocking the content and enabling some functions:

The problem is when I activate the mode I get this error:

```
node_modules\tinymce\tinymce.min.js:4 problem while activating editor mode testMode: TypeError: s.activate is not a function
```

I've tried few ways to implement this mode, for example:

```
class TestMode implements EditorModeApi {
  activate(): void {
    console.log('mode activated');    
  }

  deactivate(): void {
    console.log('mode deactivated');
  }

  editorReadOnly: boolean = true;
}
```

Then in setup:

```
setup: async (editor: any) => {
    editor.mode.register('testMode', new TestMode());
}
```

And finally later in code:

```
this.tinyMce.editor.mode.set('testMode');
```

I get the error.

I cannot find any example of implementing this, so help. Please.

Answer (score 2):

If you need TinyMCE content to be uneditable, but keep access to other editor controls, you can set `editable_root` to `false`.

([Documentation article just in case](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/content-behavior-options/#editable_root))