# How can I keep using inline toolbar when editor is disabled?

Tags: tinymce, uitoolbar, tinymce-react

I have an editor which uses an inline toolbar for manipulating text, as well as adding comments to a text range, refining text range using AI, etc.

For users with edit access I have no problem showing that toolbar using `addContextToolbar`.

For users who have readonly access to the text, I want to keep using the toolbar, but this time only show the "Add Comment" button. This is also fairly trivial to do. I make a new toolbar using the same `addContextToolbar` function, this time with a different predicate.

Unfortunately, showing toolbars is disabled when the entire editor is disabled (for users with read access). Also I recently learned that using `@tinymce/tinymce-react` and passing `readonly: true` to `init` doesn't do anything. Only way to disable editor is by using the `disabled` prop.

Is there any way to keep being able to show toolbars in `disabled` mode? I really don't want to make my own toolbar (there are no examples online anyway). I also don't want to make my own "readonly" mode, where I ignore all keystrokes and make the caret transparent.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77142197/1563544). Setting `editable_root` to `false` makes the editor not editable, but inline toolbars keep working.

If this helped be sure to upvote the original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77142197/1563544).